# error when trying to keep order of dictonary as it was found

Tags: python, syntax-error

I want the dictionary to be kept in the same order that the dates are found so  the dictionary is order by date.  I looked at [this python site](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) but the code does not work I get and error when trying to use this class. Any ideas why and how I can fix it?

```
page = str('<OPTION VALUE="08/25/2013" >08/25/2013</OPTION><OPTIONVALUE="09/01/2013">09/01/2013</OPTION><OPTION VALUE="09/08/2013" >09/08/2013</OPTION><OPTION VALUE="09/15/2013" >09/15/2013</OPTION><OPTION VALUE="09/22/2013" >09/22/2013</OPTION><OPTION VALUE="09/29/2013" >09/29/2013</OPTION><OPTION VALUE="10/06/2013" >10/06/2013</OPTION><OPTION VALUE="10/13/2013" >10/13/2013</OPTION><OPTION VALUE="10/20/2013">10/20/2013</OPTION><OPTIONVALUE="10/27/2013">10/27/2013</OPTION><OPTION VALUE="11/03/2013" >11/03/2013</OPTION><OPTION VALUE="11/10/2013" >11/10/2013</OPTION><OPTION VALUE="11/17/2013" >11/17/2013</OPTION><OPTION VALUE="11/24/2013" >11/24/2013</OPTION><OPTION VALUE="12/01/2013" >12/01/2013</OPTION><OPTION VALUE="12/08/2013" >12/08/2013</OPTION><OPTION VALUE="12/15/2013" >12/15/2013</OPTION>OPTION VALUE="12/22/2013" >12/22/2013</OPTION><OPTION VALUE="12/29/2013" >12/29/2013</OPTION><OPTION VALUE="01/05/2014" >01/05/2014</OPTION><OPTION VALUE="01/12/2014" >01/12/2014</OPTION><OPTION VALUE="01/19/2014" >01/19/2014</OPTION><OPTION VALUE="01/26/2014" >01/26/2014</OPTION><OPTION VALUE="02/02/2014" >02/02/2014</OPTION><OPTION VALUE="02/09/2014" >02/09/2014</OPTION><OPTION VALUE="02/16/2014" >02/16/2014</OPTION><OPTION VALUE="02/23/2014" >02/23/2014</OPTION><OPTION VALUE="03/02/2014" >03/02/2014</OPTION><OPTION VALUE="03/09/2014" >03/09/2014</OPTION><OPTION VALUE="03/16/2014" >03/16/2014</OPTION><OPTION VALUE="03/23/2014" >03/23/2014</OPTION><OPTION VALUE="03/30/2014" >03/30/2014</OPTION><OPTION VALUE="04/06/2014" >04/06/2014</OPTION><OPTION VALUE="04/13/2014" >04/13/2014</OPTION><OPTION VALUE="04/20/2014" >04/20/2014</OPTION><OPTION VALUE="04/27/2014" >04/27/2014</OPTION><OPTION VALUE="05/04/2014" >05/04/2014</OPTION><OPTION VALUE="05/11/2014" >05/11/2014</OPTION><OPTION VALUE="05/18/2014" >05/18/2014</OPTION><OPTION VALUE="05/25/2014" >05/25/2014</OPTION><OPTION VALUE="06/01/2014" >06/01/2014</OPTION><OPTION VALUE="06/08/2014" >06/08/2014</OPTION><OPTION VALUE="06/15/2014" >06/15/2014</OPTION>')


def web_link (enter_web_link):
#11%2F10%2F2013
    enter_web_link =  enter_web_link.replace("/","%") #00%00%0000
    add_twoF = enter_web_link[:3]+"2F"+ enter_web_link[3:]  #00%2F00%0000
    add_twoF_everywhere = add_twoF[:8] +"2F"+add_twoF[8:]
    add_twoF_everywhere = str(add_twoF_everywhere)
    return  add_twoF_everywhere

def search_13(page):
    starter = '<OPTION VALUE="' # find the postion where this starts
    start_link = page.find(starter)
    starter = len(starter)
    if start_link == -1:
        return None, 0, None 
    start_link = start_link + starter
    end_date = start_link + 10
    datetext  = page[start_link: end_date]
    str_date = str(datetext) #this is hte actuall normal looking date dd/mm/yyyy
    enter_web_link = str_date # this will enter we_link function to change to percent signs
    endoflinkdate = web_link(enter_web_link)
    return str_date , end_date,  endoflinkdate


def getalllinks(page):
    links = {}  
    while True:
        str_date,end_date,endoflinkdate = search_13(page)
        if str_date:
            links[str_date] ='link' +  endoflinkdate
            page = page[end_date:]
        else:
            break
    return links



work = getalllinks(page)
print work

class OrderedCounter(Counter, OrderedDict):  #THIS DOES NOT WORK CAUSES ERRORS 
    def __repr__(self):
        return '%s(%r)' % (self.__class__.__name__, OrderedDict(self))
    def __reduce__(self):
        return self.__class__, (OrderedDict(self),)
var1 = OrderedCounter(page,links)
print var1
```

error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "schedule.py", line 43, in <module>
        class OrderedCounter(Counter, OrderedDict):
    NameError: name 'Counter' is not defined
```

how is it not defined its a parameter?

I want this as a dictionary as {date:link, date:link} I can get this but it is not in the same order of the dates in variable page. I want the order to be the same as the dates are found in variable page so 08/25/2013: link, 09/01/2013:link,

I want to keep it in a dictionary because I paste it in a javascript website so I can enter a date and get the link and also have an ordered scroll down menu.

Comment: Don't use a dictionary then. Perhaps a list might work?

Comment: Please please please don't just say errors occur.  Specifically state what output you are seeing, and what output you expect.  Put this information as an edit to your post, not in a comment.

Comment: it would probably help to see the specific error text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use things from Python libraries, you need to import the library first:

```
from collections import OrderedDict, Counter
```

Comment: I have grave doubts that multiple inheritance from `OrderedDict` and `Counter` works as the OP appears to expect, but I admit I haven't tested that.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper I suppose I should have put in a disclaimer that I wasn't 100% certain that what he was trying to do is going to work.

Comment: I think the OP thought that the class inheritance is actually the parameters passed to `__init__`

Comment: then how would you order it?